# Graph from Code Behind Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key ERROR

Tags: asp.net, graph, syncfusion

I am trying to use Syncfusion graph via codebehind. I found this link and sample program as below link.

https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/130261/create-charts-dynamically-base-on-user-data

http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/forum/130261/ze/Sample-503161674

I was able to run the sample project without issue, the graph shown as expected. However when I tried to copied the same code to my project and run it, I keep getting an error as below. Anybody can shed a light where did I do wrongly?

> Server Error in '/' Application. Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   key Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution
>   of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: key
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key]
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key) +12756140 
>   Syncfusion.JavaScript.EssentialJavaScript.RegisterControl(String id,
>   String jsonData) +26    Syncfusion.JavaScript.Control.RenderJson()
>   +224    Syncfusion.JavaScript.Control.Raw() +98    Syncfusion.JavaScript.Control.ToHtmlString() +8
>   Syncfusion.JavaScript.Web.Chart.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +51
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter) +129
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter) +287
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +27
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children) +197
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +9
>   System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter) +129
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter) +287
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +27
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children) +197
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +177
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +32
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.Render(HtmlTextWriter output) +357
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter) +129
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter) +287
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +53
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children) +197
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +9
>   System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +30
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter) +129
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter) +287
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +27
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +5626
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.8.4075.0

As a matter of fact, I tried to use ajaxcontroltoolkit graph, also get the same error. There must be some setting or configuration error from my project. But I couldn't catch it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: error in writing, usually in url

Answer (score -1):

We have analyzed the query. From that, we suspect that the reported scenario occurs due to the improper configuration of the web.config file in your project.

Please see

- https://forums.asp.net/t/1686073.aspx?Value+cannot+be+null+Parameter+name+requestUriString+when+implementing+Payment+solution+in+Visual+Studio
- https://forums.iis.net/t/1217783.aspx

Please check the project configuration and let us know if you still facing the issue.